# Why does lower latency of audio devices translate to higher CPU consumption?

Tags: audio, cpu, cpu-usage, audio-processing

I'm wondering what the relation is between operating an audio device at a lower latency and it using more CPU power.

**Can you explain it to me?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve lower latency the CPU has to service interrupts from the device more often and so move data in smaller chunks - so more chunks will have to be moved. It turns out that the setup and teardown (the overhead) to move a chunk of data to or from a device is significant. So the fewer chunks/second you're handling, the less the load on the CPU.

However, modern CPUs are so powerful that the difference shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: Spot on. A reference would be nice but, heck, +1 anyway because this is the correct answer.

Comment: My analogy for this is working in an office where people keep interrupting you. Each interruption involves a lot of your time (who are you, why are you here, what do you need from me, let me see what I can do, etc). If these interruptions happen frequently enough, you spend all your time context switching and getting no real work done.